# QLabel with only one bold line

Tags: qt, qlabel

Suppose I have a `QLabel` with a multiline text in; this multiline text comes from a text file: I open the text file, read a line at a time and put the read line into the `QLabel` followed by a "\n" (CR).

When I reach the end of file, my `QLabel` shows all read text line per line.
During the read phase I'm able to detect if the read line contains a searched word: in this case I would put this entire line in Bold character, while all the other lines still remain in no bold font.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your base text does not contain html code, you could set the format of your QLabel to RichText, using 
`label.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);`.
This way, it will interprete your text as html.
Surround the line you want to highlight with `<b></b>` - that should do the trick.

Alternatively to `setTextFormat()`, you could surround your entire text with `<html></html>`. See [`mightBeRichText()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#mightBeRichText) documentation as well.

Try setting the text format by calling
`ui->InfoTextLabel->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);`

The line you want to make bold should be surrounded with `<b></b>`, so you can append it to your text like this:
`append("<b>" + line + "</b>\n")`

Have a look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop)

Answer (score 0):

In details, my operation:

1) opening the txt file as qtextstream

```
Info.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream in(&Info);
```

2) look for searched text in every read line and append every lines to complete text for QLabel:

```
while (!line.isNull())
{
    if (line.contains(mytext)
    {
        // do something to bold the entire line
        ui->InfoTextLabel->setText(totline.append(line + "\n"));
    }
}
```

3) Final result:

```
line1
**mytext**
line3
```

Thus, at the end, only one of the three or more line must be Bold.
I need further indication about.

Comment: I edited my answer with some more guidance. Consider giving it a try